# SQL Server query for events filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

We do have a table Events and store events using followoing columns

```
EventID INT
EventName VARCHAR(50)
BeginMonth TINYINT
BeginDay TINYINT
EndMonth TINYINT
EndDay TINYINT
```

Below are some examples of **`records`**

```
EventID EventName  BeginMonth BeginDay EndMonth EndDay
  1      Event-1     3           1        6      17
  2      Event-2     5           10       8      15
  3      Event-3     11           5       2      13
```

Please Note : We don't store year value since events occur every year so it might be possible that endmonth less than beginmonth (record no 3). It means event is starting one year and ending the next

Now I want a ms sql query that should give all events based on current date. It would be good if we don't use year for current date.

Comment: And your attempt at writing the query is..

Comment: What would really be good is to use date fields to store dates. And show us some code too...

Comment: **`select datepart(day,getdate())
select datepart(month,getdate())`**. I can't provide you the exact answer, as i am busy with other stuff, But the above two Query are very useful in your case.

Comment: Please, tag SQL Server-related questions as "sql-server", not "sql" and "server". Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

<s>If I got your Question right, the following **`Query`** will work for You.</s>

```
Select *

FROM Events
WHERE --CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) BETWEEN
CONVERT(date,dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)) BETWEEN
CAST((CAST(case when CAST([BeginMonth] as Varchar)> (select datepart(month,getdate())) 
THEN (select datepart(YEAR,getdate())-1)
when CAST([BeginMonth] as Varchar)= (select datepart(month,getdate()))
AND CAST([BeginDay] as Varchar)> (select datepart(month,getdate()))
THEN (select datepart(YEAR,getdate())-1)
when CAST([BeginMonth] as Varchar)= (select datepart(month,getdate()))
AND CAST([BeginDay] as Varchar)= (select datepart(month,getdate()))
THEN (select datepart(YEAR,getdate()))
when CAST([BeginMonth] as Varchar)= (select datepart(month,getdate()))
AND CAST([BeginDay] as Varchar)< (select datepart(month,getdate()))
THEN (select datepart(YEAR,getdate())) 
ELSE (select datepart(YEAR,getdate())) END AS VARCHAR)
+'-'+
CAST([BeginMonth] as Varchar)
+'-'+
CAST([BeginDay] as Varchar)) as DATE) 
AND
CAST((CAST(case when CAST([BeginMonth] as Varchar)> (select datepart(month,getdate())) 
THEN (select datepart(YEAR,getdate())-1)
when CAST([BeginMonth] as Varchar)= (select datepart(month,getdate()))
AND CAST([BeginDay] as Varchar)> (select datepart(month,getdate()))
THEN (select datepart(YEAR,getdate())-1)
when CAST([BeginMonth] as Varchar)= (select datepart(month,getdate()))
AND CAST([BeginDay] as Varchar)= (select datepart(month,getdate()))
THEN (select datepart(YEAR,getdate()))
when CAST([BeginMonth] as Varchar)= (select datepart(month,getdate()))
AND CAST([BeginDay] as Varchar)< (select datepart(month,getdate()))
THEN (select datepart(YEAR,getdate())) 
ELSE (select datepart(YEAR,getdate()))+1 END AS VARCHAR)
+'-'+
CAST([BeginMonth] as Varchar)
+'-'+
CAST([BeginDay] as Varchar)) as DATE)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d44b/1)**

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d44b/2)**

I got my **`Mistake.`**

```
Select *

FROM Event
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) BETWEEN

CAST((CAST(case when CAST([BeginMonth] as Varchar)> (select datepart(month,getdate())) 
THEN (select datepart(YEAR,getdate())-1)
when CAST([BeginMonth] as Varchar)= (select datepart(month,getdate()))
AND CAST([BeginDay] as Varchar)> (select datepart(month,getdate()))
THEN (select datepart(YEAR,getdate())-1)
when CAST([BeginMonth] as Varchar)= (select datepart(month,getdate()))
AND CAST([BeginDay] as Varchar)= (select datepart(month,getdate()))
THEN (select datepart(YEAR,getdate()))
when CAST([BeginMonth] as Varchar)= (select datepart(month,getdate()))
AND CAST([BeginDay] as Varchar)< (select datepart(month,getdate()))
THEN (select datepart(YEAR,getdate())) 
ELSE (select datepart(YEAR,getdate())) END AS VARCHAR)
+'-'+
CAST([BeginMonth] as Varchar)
+'-'+
CAST([BeginDay] as Varchar)) as DATE) 
AND
CAST((CAST(case when CAST([EndMonth] as Varchar)> (select datepart(month,getdate())) 
THEN (select datepart(YEAR,getdate()))
when CAST([EndMonth] as Varchar)= (select datepart(month,getdate()))
AND CAST([EndDay] as Varchar)> (select datepart(month,getdate()))
THEN (select datepart(YEAR,getdate()))
when CAST([EndMonth] as Varchar)= (select datepart(month,getdate()))
AND CAST([EndDay] as Varchar)= (select datepart(month,getdate()))
THEN (select datepart(YEAR,getdate())+1)
when CAST([EndMonth] as Varchar)= (select datepart(month,getdate()))
AND CAST([EndDay] as Varchar)< (select datepart(month,getdate()))
THEN (select datepart(YEAR,getdate())+1) 
ELSE (select datepart(YEAR,getdate())) END AS VARCHAR)
+'-'+
CAST([EndMonth] as Varchar)
+'-'+
CAST([EndDay] as Varchar)) as DATE)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf881/3)**

I hope this time you will be satisfied.

In case you don't want to use **`Today's`** Date and you have a **`Predefined`** date then please replace **`GETDATE()`** to your **`predefined`** Datetime value.

Yes it **`Datetime`**

Comment: Hi Luv, sorry, if i am doing wrong but your query does not work for me. It also select below records  : EventID: 10, EventName: my event, BeginMonth: 4, BeginDay: 20, EndMonth: 6 and EndDay: 9 even today is 6/11/2013 current month: 6 and currentday: 11

Comment: @RaviBhartiya What's your Error?

Comment: so that record should not show since it already finished on 6/9

Comment: Which record/event you are talking about

Comment: sorry for delay. I am talking about the events those start on 4/20 and end on 6/9.

Comment: @RaviBhartiya Please try Again

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31578/discussion-between-ravi-bhartiya-and-luv)

Comment: Hi Luv, if possbile try to save (4, 'Event-4', 4, 10, 6, 9) record and then re-run SQL server query and then see it would still show this record even this should not be. Please note: 6/9 < 6/11 (today date)

Comment: @RaviBhartiya Please have a look to my final updated answer.

Comment: hi Luv, sorry but your query is still not giving correct record. Why is it selecting events start on 9/9 (beginmonth/beginday) and end on 10/16 (endmonth/endday). Please try to save (5, 'Event-5', 9, 9, 10, 16) and run your query.